# Variance of estimator(exponential distribution)

Tags: self-study, variance, estimators, method-of-moments

I have exponential distributed data $Exp(\lambda)$ with sample n = 50. Also, The sample mean = 2.17. I need to find the estimator of parameter $\lambda$ by the method of moments and to build 95% confidence interval.

We know, that by the method of moments we got the estimation the parameter $\lambda$ = $1/\bar X$.

Now for confidence interval of my estimator i must calculate the variance of estimator: $Var(\hat \lambda)$ = $Var(1/\bar X)$

But now i am not sure what to do. My attempt: $1/Var(\bar X) = 1/Var(\sum (1/n) *X_i)$ and by the propery o variance i got the result $\lambda^2 * n$.

But i doubt, that is correct result. Can you please help me?
many thanks

Comment: Please provide some context: how were your data obtained and what distributional assumptions are you making?

Comment: If this is a homework problem, please add the `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: Added to the main post

Answer (score 2):

$$Var\left(\dfrac{1}{\bar{X}} \right) \ne \dfrac{1}{Var(\bar{X})}.$$

So what you have is indeed incorrect. To solve the problem, go through the following steps:

1. What is the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$?
2. What is the distribution of $\bar{X}$?
3. What is the distribution of $Y = 1/\bar{X}$?
4. What is $Var(Y)$?

Comment: 1. This is surely gamma distribution

2.Expected value of gamma distribution

3. It will be 1/E(gamma distribution)

Am i on the right way of thinking?

Comment: @DanielYefimov No, E(1/Gamma) is not 1/E(Gamma). You need to find the distribution of the "inverse" of a Gamma. And then, find the expectation of that inverse.

Comment: It should be the inverse-gamma distribution.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution

And then expecation of this distribution. Finally, the variance of the inverse-gamma distribution. I think, that i am right in this case.
Sorry for stupid questions:)
And thanks for a help

Comment: @DanielYefimov That sounds correct.

Comment: @Daniel I presume you realize by now, but just in case you didn't catch on to this issue yet, your original answer to Greenparker's q2 is wrong; the distribution of $\bar{X}$ is not the expected value of the variable you're averaging.

Comment: Maybe the answer to the second question is the gamma distribution with parameters: $\Gamma(\lambda, \lambda/n)$? If yes, can you please explain detailed how do we got this result?
And the answers on the next questions are true?